# Beginning with event listeners

Tags: java, user-interface, image, events

I have a simple app, showing picture made of tiled images(named u1, u2,...,u16.jpg). Now I'd like to add some Events to it, so that I can show these images only when proper button is clicked. I've tried doing it on my own, but it's not working. Where am I doing something wrong?

Original code :

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class Tiles_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Usmiech");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));
        JLabel l = new JLabel();

        for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
            String path = "u"+ i+".jpg";
            l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(path));
            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            panel.add(l);
        }

        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

New code :

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Zad_8_1 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton)(e.getSource());
        String i = b.getText();
        b = new JButton(new ImageIcon("u"+i+".jpg"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Smile");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));
        JButton l = null;

        for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
            String path = "u"+ i+".jpg";
            l = new JButton(""+i);
            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            l.setSize(53,53);
            panel.add(l);
        }

        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This should work like this :
[this http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/3129/lab8a.jpg](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/3129/lab8a.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have constructor to add event listeners.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                render("Window");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void render(String s){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Smile");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Pane pan = new Pane();
        f.add(pan);
        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

    class Pane extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        Pane(){
            setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));
            JButton l = null;
            for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
                l = new JButton(""+i);
                l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
                l.addActionListener(this);
                l.setSize(53,53);
                add(l);
            }
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton)(e.getSource());
        String i = b.getText();
        b.setIcon(new ImageIcon("u"+i+".jpg"));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try registering the buttons to listen for the event like this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
        String path = "u"+ i+".jpg";
        l = new JButton(""+i);
        l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        l.setSize(53,53);
        l.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(l);
    }
```

Comment: +1, for being the first to mention adding the ActionListener (I assumed that was done when I posted my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reassigning `b` a new instance of `JButton`, you should simply reset the icon:

```
b.setIcon(new ImageIcon("u"+i+".jpg"));
```

(take a look at pass by reference/pass by value concepts in Java, [well explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference/73021#73021))

on top of that, you need to follow Vincent's advice and actually register with all of the buttons as an `ActionListener`

```
l.addActionListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = new JButton(new ImageIcon("u"+i+".jpg"));
```

Creating a new button doesn't do anything the button just sits there in memory as it hasn't been added to the GUI.

The simple solution is to just reset the icon:

```
b.setIcon( new ImageIcon(...) );
```